# What is the meaning of division for quasigroups in here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quasigroups

I am reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29#Types_of_magmas). It says that a quasigroup is a magma in which division is always possible. I'm a little confuse with the meaning of *division*. Does *division* means that the inverse operation of $\bullet$ is always defined? I am thinking about the analogy in multiplication of integers, in which division is the inverse operation of multiplication. I guess *divison* implies that there are inverses.

Comment: Read the quasigroup axioms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

Comment: @vadim123 Oh yes. Sorry. I was too lazy that I didn't even think about googling *quasigroups*. I blame the lack of coffee.

Comment: No need to google, just click the word "quasigroups" in the link you gave. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since quasigroups are sometimes called *division groupoids* or

> *magmas where division is always possible*

(this latter from the Wikipedia page you referenced), a bit of confusion may arise.

I suggest not to confuse *division* with *division and cancellation* and to read the proper definition of both in [this article](http://www.math.md/files/basm/y2007-n2/y2007-n2-%28pp43-54%29.pdf).